# Is it possible to particularly use the default implementation of a function?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

My code works. I just would like to know if it is possible to just add something in an instance declaration to be checked first before using the default implementation, instead of having to copy the code. An example:

```
class (Eq a, Ord a, Show a, Num a) => Fibo a where
  fib :: a -> a
  fib n
    | n == 0 = 0
    | n == 1 = 1
    | otherwise = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

instance Fibo Integer where
  fib n
    | n < 0 = -1
    | n == 0 = 0
    | n == 1 = 1
    | otherwise = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

But can it also be written in a way where I dont have to re-implement the whole function? Something like:

```
instance Fibo Integer where
  fib n
    | n < 0 = -1
    | otherwise = default
```

Or is there any other way to do without using the same code in two places?

The Solution is NOT to change the default implementation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the common code to a helper function:

```
foo::(Eq a, Ord a, Show a, Num a) =>a -> a
foo n
    | n == 0 = 0
    | n == 1 = 1
    | otherwise = foo (n-1) + foo (n-2)

class (Eq a, Ord a, Show a, Num a) => Fibo a where
  fib :: a -> a
  fib = foo

instance Fibo Integer where
  fib n
    | n < 0 = -1
    | otherwise = foo n
```

Comment: It is worth noting that if you don't want `foo` to be part of the public interface of your code, you can just leave it out of the export list of your module.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i hoped for a single command after `otherwise =` without having to change something else, but that will do.